# How to point `sam local start-api` at a custom build?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I have a C# lambda and I am trying to locally test different builds of it (with different preprocessor symbols set, etc). I am able to produce these different builds with things like `dotnet lambda package -c Debug`, but **what I don't know how to do is point the `sam local start-api` command at my build**.

To be clear, I am able to get `sam local start-api` working when I build via `sam build`, but it appears that I then cannot control the dotnet build "configuration", hence using `dotnet lambda package` instead.

The aws [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-start-api.html) say:

> For more compiled languages or projects that require complex packing support, we recommend that you run your own building solution, and point AWS SAM to the directory or file that contains the build artifacts.

but I don't see any way to point the command at my custom build. Anybody know how to do this? Am I missing something obvious?